# How to solve the issue of the group title being cut off?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

this is my first time to ask questions in stack overflow.
Recently I have done a bit of data visualization on the Amino Acids by making a multiple pie charts
First, this is my dataset

```
library(ggplot2)
df = data.frame(Species <-c('Chicken','Chicken','Chicken','Chicken','Chicken','Human','Human','Human','Human','Human','Crab-eating macaque','Crab-eating macaque','Crab-eating macaque','Crab-eating macaque','Crab-eating macaque','Mouse','Mouse','Mouse','Mouse','Mouse','Zebrafish','Zebrafish','Zebrafish','Zebrafish','Zebrafish'),
                Amino_acids <- c('E','R','G','P','Others','E','R','G','P','Others','E','R','G','P','Others','E','R','G','P','Others','E','R','G','P','Others'),
                value <- c(18,6,10,9,57,26,14,8,5,46,29,15,10,4,42,23,17,7,5,48,31,4,13,7,46))

df$Species <- factor(df$Species)
df$Amino_acids <- factor(df$Amino_acids)
```

Then, using ggplot2 to make the data visualization

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=" ", y=value, group=Amino_acids, colour=Amino_acids, fill=Amino_acids)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity", position= "fill") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0)+
  facet_grid(.~ Species) + facet_wrap(.~Species, strip.position="top")+theme_void()
```

and the result is this
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EheY.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EheY.png)

The problem is I dont know why some of the group (species) titles are being cut off, for example, crab-eating macaque, that is very confusing to me. Also, I have tried hjust on the axis.title.x and y already and it seems no use at all.

Can anyone solve this issue for me? I would rly appreciate it if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to edit `strip.title.x`. You have several ways to go around this. I'd prefer editing the box size for the text:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=" ", y=value, group=Amino_acids, colour=Amino_acids, fill=Amino_acids)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity", position= "fill") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0)+
  facet_grid(.~ Species) + 
  facet_wrap(.~Species) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(1,0,1,0), "cm"))
```

However, you could also adjust the vertical position:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=" ", y=value, group=Amino_acids, colour=Amino_acids, fill=Amino_acids)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity", position= "fill") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0)+
  facet_grid(.~ Species) + 
  facet_wrap(.~Species) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(vjust = 1))
```

Both should result in this:
[image]